# jQuery .hover script

Tags: hover

I am pretty new to jQuery and here is my problem with this [website](http://www.sinaphotographystudio.com/).

As you see, There is a some small pictures in the right. I wrote a very simple script with HOVER in order to change the opacity of the element when mouse over. But this doesn't work until I do a small change in that script in Firebug (e.g. just by press space in any line of script it becomes active). and then it works! I completely confused by this.

If anyone can help me through, I can correct the same problem with another script that change the position of those small pictures as you move over.

I am searching for any solution that can do the same thing as I want.

Thank you
and goodbye presently.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your calls to .hover() in $(document).ready() calls like you have in some of your other script nodes because the images are not loaded in the page yet when those calls are executed. For example, this:

```
  $('.s1').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).stop().css('z-index','9998').animate({left:-40});
  },
  function () {
    $(this).stop().css('z-index','').animate({left:-80});
  }
);
```

should be this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.s1').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).stop().css('z-index','9998').animate({left:-40});
  },
  function () {
    $(this).stop().css('z-index','').animate({left:-80});
  }
);
})
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You are welcome! Please accept the answer so the question doesn't show up as "Unanswered".